# How do I interact with the previous element in a div?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a simple HTML script that shows a piece of text aligned to the left, and when hovered it reveals another piece of text. When shown, the text should be centered and directly above the hovered element's text *or* if the revealed text is longer than the original text, left aligned. It should also work for any length of text.

I cannot figure out how to make it work when the "answer" is above the "question". I tried not having them in the same "container" and just positioning the answer above using relative and absolute positions, but I couldn't figure out how to make it align properly with that route. I could only get it to center on with the width of the whole page.

```css
.hide {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.myDIV:hover+.hide {
  opacity: 1;
}

.myDIV {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}

.myContainer {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="myContainer">
  <div class="myDIV">Question</div>
  <div class="hide">Answer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: _'how to make it work when the "answer" is above the "question"'_ - and by "above", you mean - in the source code order, or on the z-axis, when both elements _are_ in the same position, because you positioned one of them absolute?

Comment: Above in the source code order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this. This doesn't cover all the cases, but it might give you an idea.

```css
.hide {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    opacity:0;
    font-size: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
   white-space: nowrap;
}
    
.myDIV:hover + .hide {
    opacity: 1;
}

.myDIV {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: left;
}

.myContainer {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myContainer">
    <div class="myDIV">Question</div>
    <div class="hide">Answer Answer Answer Answer</div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="myContainer">
    <div class="myDIV">Question</div>
    <div class="hide">Answer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with, should work with your case. You can also use wrapping.

```css
.hide {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.myContainer:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.myContainer:hover .hide {
  opacity: 1;
  top: -0.5em; /* adjust to your preference */
}

.myDIV {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}

.myContainer {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="myContainer">
      <div class="myDIV">Question</div>
      <div class="hide">Answer</div>
    </div>
    <div class="myContainer">
      <div class="myDIV">Question</div>
      <div class="hide">AnswerAnswerAnswerAnswerAnswer</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```